# Is there a bintray java API?

Tags: bintray

I was wondering if there was a Java wrapper for the bintray REST api. I could just use some java REST consuming services, but if it already exists it would be much easier, I don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Bintray client Java](https://github.com/bintray/bintray-client-java) module.
You can import it to your Java project as it is available on [Jcenter](https://bintray.com/jfrog/bintray-tools/bintray-client-java).

*Update:*
In order to install dependencies from JCenter, you need to add JCenter to your repository resolver. You need to add this to your `POM.xml`:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
<repositories>
```

> Note: you can have more than one repository under the `<repositories>` label

Comment: I added 

```xml
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jfrog.bintray.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>bintray-client-java-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
```

but for some reason it says `Dependency 'com.jfrog.bintray.client:bintray-client-java-api:0.9.2' not found`

Comment: I have tried it on my local setup and it work. I would recommend to 1) Add JCenter to your resolved repositories     
```<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
<repositories>```   

2) remove the `<type>pom</type>` 3) check if the dependency exists in your `.m2` directory.

Comment: I already added the JCenter repo, changing http to https fixed it, thanks